# Removing .php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Well, I know that it should be done by .htaccess
my .htaccess is in the root of my site and here it's content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Also mod rewrite is enabled at my server.
 I have a form with an action on `./getReadings.php` in it.
But when I change it to `./getReadings` it says that tehre isn't such file on server. What's my mistake?

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` before `RewriteEngine` directive

Comment: Perfect, dude! Post an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `Options -MultiViews` before `RewriteEngine` directive

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Note: `MultiViews` is about Apache content negociation (which is the problem here since `filename` will automatically be translated as `filename.php` existing file). That's why you have to disable it.

---

EDIT: right now, you can access same content by 2 different urls (with or without `php` extension). To avoid duplicate content (which is bad for search engines) you can redirect extensions to extensionless equivalent with this code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code only. You should also add an explanation of what the code is doing.